# How do implement jQuery autocomplete in Google App Engine with Python?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, autocomplete

I found several sources discussing this problem, ([this one seems the simplest but it is for PHP](http://www.codeunit.co.za/2011/08/12/php-how-to-implement-jquery-autocomplete-using-a-json-datasource/)). I will be using an existing search form and I created `AutocompleteResponse` handler to handle the request. I don't understand from the documentation if it is required that the data sent will be in json format or an array of string is ok. I am not sure about what information to send either. I created a new model with search history

```
class Search(db.Model):
    owner = db.UserProperty()
    date= db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    query = db.StringListProperty()
```

and I want to send the relevant query suggestions to autocomplete. Any help to examples whether in documentation or otherwise is welcome. Thanks.

**Update**

I put this just before the closing `</body>`

```
<script>
$('#search_form').autocomplete({
            source: "http://ting-1.appspot.com/autocomp",
            minLength: 2});
</script>
```

in my `Autocomp` handler I put

```
data = json.dumps("abc, def")
```

I naively think that `data` will be passed to jquery autocomplete plug in. But nothing is happenning. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried this and it worked:

```
    data = ['cat','dog','bird', 'wolf']
    data = json.dumps(data)         
    self.response.out.write(data)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! This worked. But I needed to add `<input id="search_form"`> to my form. Also, I think I was expecting something like "google-type" autocomplete but this is same as the browser autocomplete, so now I am not sure why use jQuery instead of going with the browser autocomplete. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zeynel Because the browser autocomplete will only include data the user has entered previously; this will include any data you want. To have the autocomplete data depend on what's entered, write your handler to accept the string so far and generate suggestions from that.